# Parallelizing pandas pyodbc SQL database calls

Tags: python, sql, multithreading, pandas, pyodbc

I am currently querying data into dataframe via the `pandas.io.sql.read_sql()` command. I wanted to parallelize the calls similar to what this guys is advocating: ([Embarrassingly parallel database calls with Python (PyData Paris 2015 )](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0eNQSzIbpQ))

Something like (very general):

```
pools = [ThreadedConnectionPool(1,20,dsn=d) for d in dsns]
connections = [pool.getconn() for pool in pools]
parallel_connection = ParallelConnection(connections)
pandas_cursor = parallel_connection.cursor()
pandas_cursor.execute(my_query)
```

Is something like that possible?

Comment: what is your SQL database type and driver, and do they support multi-threaded calls?

Comment: using MS sql server, it does support multi-threaded calls

Comment: not sure about pyodbc, but since 2013 pymssql seems to be thread-safe for multi-threading: http://pymssql.org/en/latest/changelog.html?highlight=threading

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this should work, although with the caveat that you'll need to change parallel_connection.py in that talk that you site.  In that code there's a `fetchall` function which executes each of the cursors in parallel, then combines the results.  This is the core of what you'll change:

Old Code:

```
def fetchall(self):
    results = [None] * len(self.cursors)
    def do_work(index, cursor):
        results[index] = cursor.fetchall()
    self._do_parallel(do_work)
    return list(chain(*[rs for rs in results]))
```

New Code:

```
def fetchall(self):
    results = [None] * len(self.sql_connections)
    def do_work(index, sql_connection):
        sql, conn = sql_connection  #  Store tuple of sql/conn instead of cursor
        results[index] = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
    self._do_parallel(do_work)
    return pd.DataFrame().append([rs for rs in results])
```

Repo:  https://github.com/godatadriven/ParallelConnection

Comment: is it possible to show a example on how you actually pass a query `sql, conn = sql_connection` basically we need to pass tuple of sql and connection?.

Comment: It's been a few years, so I don't fully remember the context - but it looks like from the linked code that you would pass in an array of `(sql, conn)` tuples to the constructor of ParallelConnection.  Something like `ParallelConnection([(sql1, con1), (sql2, con2)])`

Comment: so no need to call `execute()` while passing a query string? just like in the question...

Comment: In the above example, I used `fetchall` instead of `execute`, but you can do the same thing with `execute`.  After initializing the ParallelConnection with the array of tuples, call either `execute` or `fetchall` and the `_do_parallel` function handles passing out the work to the individual connections/queries.