# python parallelize db query execution

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have following query that returns data between a date ranges.

```
dates = ['20100101','20100201',20100301','20100401']

query = 'select date, company_name, total_amount from info_stats where date between 'start_date' and 'end_date'
```

I obtain date ranges from another process and construct a list so that I can iterate as follows:

```
pds = []
for idx in range(0, len(dates) - 1):
   formated_query = self.get_formated_query(start_date=dates[idx].strftime('%Y%m%d'),
                                                      end_date=dates[idx + 1].strftime('%Y%m%d')
   results_df = pds.append(pd.read_sql(sql=formated_query,con=db_connect))
```

to query I am passing date at `index` and `index + 1` (date greater than date at the index)

These queries take super long time and i want to execute in a parallelize manner so that wait time is shorter. I went over `joblib` but not sure if this is `multi-threading` or `multi-processing`. Looks like the former. Also new to `joblib`, how can I parallelize above code using `joblib` or other package?

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32136276/parallelizing-pandas-pyodbc-sql-database-calls?

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite broad, but I can share my own experience with parallelising queries against databases.

What I found is that if I have many small jobs, I can use the python built-in multithreading modules such as concurrent.futures. I will get speed ups.

However, if I have big jobs that take a long time to run on the database, parallelising does not help. This is because the database engine itself (in my case SQL Server), already does a splendid job of parallelising the job. In which case, the single big job is already maximising the number of processes the server can handle - putting more jobs won’t help. Your situation seems to be the this one.